# show approve and pending documents

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

when user upload document then document save in this table and set values as 3 means this is in pedning

```
 DocID      DocName UploadedDate    Uploadfile  DocTypeID   DepID   ApproveID    UploadedBy UserID  
36        erp system 2014-02-03     Presentation1.pptx  1    4        3           noreen    21
```

and when director approve/reject this document then approveid changes to 1 e.g approve

so i want to show when first user upload document and then he/she view documents that which documents are in peding ,approve and reject

this is sp which i try

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[UserIDDoc]

@UserID int
as
Select 
 dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID as DocumentID, 
   dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName, 
 dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedDate as UploadedDate,
 dbo.DocType.DocType as Document, 

 dbo.Department.DepType as Department, 
dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded,

 dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType AS Status 

FROM 
dbo.DocumentInfo
inner JOIN dbo.DocType ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID=dbo.DocType.DocTypeID
inner JOIN dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID=dbo.Department.DepID

left join dbo.ApproveType on dbo.DocumentInfo.ApproveID=dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID
INNER JOIN dbo.Approval ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID = dbo.Approval.DocID 

 where UserID=@UserID AND dbo.Approval.DesigID = 3
```

but when i execute this sp it shows me like this

```
DocumentID  DocumentName    UploadedDate    Document    Department       FileUploaded                               Status
    36          ERP SYSTEM       2014-01-20     MSWord  Computer Science    system admin first assignment.docx  Pending
    36          ERP SYSTEM      2014-01-20  MSWord  Computer Science    system admin first assignment.docx  Pending
    36          ERP SYSTEM      2014-01-20  MSWord  Computer Science    system admin first assignment.docx  Pending
    39           def          2014-01-22    MSWord  Human Resource  BISE RAWALPINDI.docx                  Approve
```

but i want this

```
DocumentID  DocumentName    UploadedDate    Document    Department       FileUploaded                     Status
 36         ERP SYSTEM      2014-01-20  MSWord  Computer Science    system admin first assignment.docx  Pending
 39          def          2014-01-22    MSWord  Human Resource  BISE RAWALPINDI.docx                  Approve
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the DISTINCT keyword

```
 Select DISTINCT 
         dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID as DocumentID,    
         dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName,  
         dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedDate as UploadedDate,  
         dbo.DocType.DocType as Document, 
         dbo.Department.DepType as Department,  
         dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded,
         dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType AS Status 
 FROM  dbo.DocumentInfo 
 inner JOIN dbo.DocType    ON  dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID=dbo.DocType.DocTypeID 
 inner JOIN dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID=dbo.Department.DepID
 left join dbo.ApproveType on dbo.DocumentInfo.ApproveID=dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID 
 INNER JOIN  dbo.Approval ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID = dbo.Approval.DocID     
 where UserID=@UserID AND dbo.Approval.DesigID = 3
```

Comment: The DISTINCT keyword tells SQL to only show one row instead of multiple rows in all the columns are the same

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SQL Distinct Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: Could you give more information about why this is a good idea? How it should be used. Etc. Link-only answers are frowned upon on SO.